# Javascript function triggers on page refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a hyperlink and clicking on that link will run a JavaScript function. I also have a PHP variable $counter. Inside the JavaScript function, the value of $counter is increased by 1 i.e., $counter++. It works fine. But the same function also runs whenever the page is refreshed. So the value of the $counter is increased by 1 whenever the page is refreshed. I tried all the solutions available on the net like preventDefault(), clickevent handler etc., But nothing works. Please help to fix this. In the below code, I have set $counter as 0. But it loads with 1 as output. I want it to count only when the hyperlink is clicked. Here is my sample code.

```
    <?php
session_start();
require("dbconfig.php");
$counter=0;
?>
<html>
<head>  
<script>
function onclick() {     
  <?php 
   $counter++;   
  ?>    
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<a href="" type="button" onclick="check()">link text</a>
</body>

  <?php 
  //tracing counter value
    echo $counter;
    ?>  
</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide the function as well?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: pls add code.....

Comment: You will need to post your code. But I think this solution is flawed by design. Javascript will not have any persistent data after the page is refreshed, unless you use a `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

Comment: I have updated the post with sample code. I have set $counter as 0. But it loads with 1 as output. I want it to count only when the hyperlink is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

You can't mix PHP and JS code expecting that JS function will execute PHP code.

First PHP prepares output to browser, then Browser parses your JS and HTML. JS never knows about PHP code.

Click CTRL+U to view source as browser sees it - there is no PHP code.

---

JS function is not run on page refresh. PHP code is run on page refresh.

First goes PHP parser:

```
session_start();
require("dbconfig.php");
$counter=0;
$counter++;
echo $counter;
```

Then goes JS/Html parser.

At this point your JS code looks like this:

```
function onclick() {
}
```

Content of function is empty because you output nothing from PHP side.

---

To fix it move PHP var to JS var:

```
<?php
session_start();
require("dbconfig.php");
$counter=0;
?>
<html>
    <head>  
        <script>
            var jsCounter = <?= $counter; ?>

            function onclick() {     
                jsCounter++;

                console.log(jsCounter);
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="" type="button" onclick="check()">link text</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

*Note* never output after closing body tag.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the solution. Is there a way to assign jsCounter value back to $counter after the increment? Because I want to store $counter value in the database.I tried this but did not work. <?php echo $counter = "<script>document.write(jsCounter)</script>"; –

Comment: But as you said, first PHP prepares output to browser. So it is possible to echo the increased value of jsCounter (javascript) in php ($counter) at the end?

Comment: @Rajesh No, JS can't assign value back to PHP. You can use session to store value to persist it after refresh. Usually PHP and JS "talks" via Ajax requests